# Get point on the Superellipse curve

Tags: geometry

I have Superellipse curve and I want to get a point on that curve , how would I calculate the coordinate of that point ?

[image]

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Your question is a bit obscure, I'm afraid. You should try to give some more details.

Comment: @Aretino sorry for not be clear , I just edit the question hope it's clear now

Comment: What do you mean by "the coordinate of that point"? Do you need exactly that green point in the diagram? Or are you asking for a generic point on the curve? Some more details on why you need that information would be useful.

Comment: By the way: your curve is a [squircle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squircle).

Comment: @Aretino yes I mean the green point ,why I need this information ? I have two points say : (0,1) and (-1,0) I want to create some points between them that follow the curve to get a round line between the two points .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The green point in the diagram has $y=-x$ and it belongs to the curve of equation $x^4+y^4=1$. Substituting here $y=-x$ one gets $2x^4=1$, that is: $x=\pm\root4\of{1/2}$.

Your point has a negative $x$, so its coordinates are:
$$
x=-{1\over\root4\of{2}},\quad y={1\over\root4\of{2}}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

From the [Wikipedia page on Superellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse), the equation of a superellipse is given by
$$\left|\frac{x}{a}\right|^n + \left|\frac{y}{b}\right|^n = 1.$$
This means that you need at least three ($3$) points $P_1(x_1,y_1), P_2(x_2,y_2),$ and $P_3(x_3,y_3)$ in order to determine the parameters $a$, $b$ and $n$.

Comment: thank you for the clarification